# Deallocating memory on console close event

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi, visual-c++

I have c++ console an application that looks something like this:

```
SomeObj* obj;

BOOL WINAPI closeHandler(DWORD cEvent)
{
   obj->Stop();
   while( obj != 0 )
   {
       Sleep(100);
   }
   return TRUE;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler( (PHANDLER_ROUTINE)SignalHandler, true );
    obj = new SomeObj();
    obj->Execute();
    delete obj;
    return 0;
}
```

`SomeObj::Execute()` is essentially a loop that keeps running until `SomeObj::Stop()` is called. When I do a CTRL+C, I can see that the application deletes `obj` properly before exiting. However, when I click on the close button on the console window, I find out that `obj` doesn't get deleted properly.

Further debugging showed that closeHandler is actually called, but somehow `obj` just doesn't get deleted. Strangely, if I put a breakpoint on the `return 0` line and try to close the console window, I end up hitting that breakpoint and see that `obj` was deleted.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a better way to deallocate stuff on a console window close event?

Comment: How are you checking that obj was deleted?

Comment: I always put my main code in a class, I mostly call it `App`, and in that I put all my dynamic allocated memory. In the constructor of this `App`-class, I deallocate all that memory

Comment: @crowder `obj` controls some physical hardware, in the destructor of obj, an led is turned off. So I just look at whether the led is on or not.

Comment: @user1833511 do you mean destructor? most of my real code is in SomeObj as well. The destructor of SomeObj deletes all of my other dynamically allocated stuff. The reason I made obj a pointer is so that closeHandler could call the Stop() function.

Comment: Are you running Windows 7 by any chance?  Microsoft made somewhat aggressive changes there to handle badly behaving programs.  When you receive a close event notification, your process will be forcefully killed after 10 seconds.  In addition to that, your process will be forcefully killed as soon as you return from the control handler function.  So the best you can do is block in your control handler for 10 seconds and hope you are able to shutdown gracefully.

Comment: @Luke I am indeed running Windows 7, and I am aware of the behavior that you described. That's why I have the loop in the handler, waiting for main to delete obj before exiting the function. crowder pointed out that I was not waiting correctly.

Comment: Why are you using "new"? That gives you explicit responsibility to manage the lifetime of the object and ensure calling of the dtor. If you used a heap object or std::unique_ptr. Also, when you close the window you abort the app, not terminate it. You might want to set an atexit() handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way that doesn't require you to manually call delete or set the pointer to null. Use a smart pointer like [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). You also don't have to wait for the object to be deleted since cleanup will be handled properly once `Execute` finishes and `main` returns.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

// sample test object that oeprates as described in your question.    
struct Object
{
    Object() : running_(true) {}
    ~Object()
    {
        std::cout << "Object deleted" << std::endl;
    }
    void Stop() { running_ = false; }
    void Execute() { while(running_ == true); }

    bool running_;
};

// incredibly smart pointer!
std::unique_ptr<Object>   obj;

BOOL WINAPI closeHandler(DWORD)
{
    // We need to call stop on the object if it exists
    // use appropriate locks for multithreaded environment
    if(obj != nullptr)
    {
       obj->Stop();
       // no need to wait
    }
    return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler( closeHandler, true );

    // Allocate the object and execute    
    obj.reset(new Object());
    obj->Execute();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your closeHandler() routine never actually completes because it is waiting for obj to become 0 (presumably you mean "NULL" or C++11-style "nullptr" here). Deleting an object does not set pointers to it to null. I'm honestly not sure why it has this loop at all?

Comment: Yes, you are right! I added `obj = 0` after the delete statement and everything works now.

Comment: I alluded to this in my comment, but it's worth re-iterating: you probably want to use NULL (commonly defined as (void *)0) or nullptr (a new keyword in C++11 which is more type-safe than NULL), rather than 0 (which is of type integer).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that your handler isn't actually deleting the object. You specify obj as a global but do not actually delete it in the closeHandler. Maybe something like the following...

```
BOOL WINAPI HandlerRoutine(DWORD dwCtrlType)
{
  if (CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT == dwCtrlType)
  {
    if (NULL != obj)
    {
      delete obj;
      obj = NULL
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If I add a delete obj in the Handler function it would conflict with the one in the main function.